# MongoCollection findOne vs find

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to know if there is some improvement on `MongoCollection::findOne` or if is just an "alias" or "shorcut" to `MongoCollection::find` with a limit of 1, for example.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findOne()` is an alias of `find()` with a `limit(-1)`

You can see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/collection.c#L469). It does the equivalent to

`find(...).limit(-1).getNext()`.

The -1 is actually relevant. Here's a snippet from the [wire protocol docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol):

> If the number is negative, then the database will return that number
>   and close the cursor.

If you go to the shell and type `> db.collection.findOne` *(no parens)*, you can see that the function is also just a helper in the shell.

So, **"yes `findOne()` is just a helper"**.

Answer (score 2):

From the [mongo tutorials](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-FindingtheFirstDocumentInACollectionusing%7B%7BfindOne%28%29%7D%7D)...

> To show that the document we inserted in the previous step is there,
>   we can do a simple findOne() operation to get the first document in
>   the collection. This method returns a single document (rather than the
>   DBCursor that the find() operation returns), and it's useful for
>   things where there only is one document, or you are only interested in
>   the first. You don't have to deal with the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

The `MongoCollection::findOne` method will directly return the result array and the `MongoCollection::find` one will return a `MongoCursor` instance even if it is a single valued result.

Answer (score 1):

mongodb.org has an [performance test report](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1475411) where they compared findOne and find. Based on the results it would seem that findOne is 35-45% faster.

Few data points from the report:

- find_one (small, no index): 989 Ops/s
- find (small, no index): 554 Ops/s

Answer (score 0):

It is almost like an alias but instead of return you a list, it returns you an object.

Comment: findOne returns an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your search query. E.g if you search by ID, since ID is unique it would not need to limit the results because only one result would be found. If more than one record is found then it would limit the results by 1. Another difference is that `findOne` returns an array, while `find` returns a mongoCursor.